# Find the minimum number of operations to make a binary number alternating

Tags: logic

Let's say there is a binary number with length `n`. `n` is even. It is guaranteed that the number will contain `n/2` numbers of `0`'s and `n/2` number of `1`'s. In one operation it is only allowed to reverse a sub portion of that binary number.

How can we find the number of operations to make the binary number alternating(No two `0` or two `1` side by side. Example - `101010` or `010101`)

For example,

If the binary number is 01**10**, we can reverse the bold portion once and we'll get `0101`. So, the required number of operation is one.

If the binary number is 11101000, we need two operations:

- 1**11010**00, reverse the bold portion to get 1**01011**00
- 10101**10**0, reverse the bold portion to get 10101**01**0

So, the required number of operations is two.

Actually, I found out the problem [here](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1437/B)

I cannot understand the solution they provided.

**Solution**

Count the number of **00** or **11**. the answer is the maximum number of **00** or **11**.
So, for 0110. the number of 11 is 1 (0**11**0). the number of 00 is 0. So, the answer is `max(1,0) = 1`

So, for 11101000, the number of 11 is 2, One for **11**101000, another for 1**11**01000. Similarly, the number of 00 is 2. So, the answer is 2.

**Question**

Why the above solution works? Could someone please explain?

Comment: Note that $n$ is even (on codeforces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps yourself. They should be almost immediately obvious, )

**Claim 1:** Given any binary string of length $n$, let the number of consecutive 00 be $a$, and the number of consecutive 11 be $b$, then the number of "reverse a sub portion of that binary string" that we need to convert it into an alternating string is $ \lceil \frac{ a+b}{2} \rceil $.

> Hint: Every 00 or 11 will need to be the start or the end of a sub-portion, in order to become an alternating string.

**Claim 2:** For a binary string of length $n = 2k$ with $k$ 0's and $k$ 1's, then $ |a-b| \leq 1$.

> Hint: The number of 00's is equal to the number of 0's minus the number of 0-blocks.

> Hint: The number of 0-blocks and 1-blocks is at most 1 apart.

**Corollary:** For a binary string of length $n = 2k$ with $k$ 0's and $k$ 1's, the number of "reverse a sub portion of that binary string" that we need to convert it into an alternating string is $ \lceil \frac{ a+b}{2} \rceil  = \max (a,b)$.

> Hint: Use $|a-b| \leq 1$.